# Login state dependent menu using handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform, handlebars.js

I'm trying to apply the following logic:

```
var LoggedOutMenuView = Parse.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile($('#menu-logged-out-tpl').html()),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template());
    }
});

var LoggedInMenuView = Parse.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile($('#menu-logged-in-tpl').html()),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template());
    }
});

var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
if (currentUser) {
    var loggedInMenuView = new LoggedInMenuView();
    loggedInMenuView.render();
    $('.navbar-fixed').html(loggedInMenuView.el);
} else {
    var loggedOutMenuView = new LoggedOutMenuView();
    loggedOutMenuView.render();
    $('.navbar-fixed').html(loggedOutMenuView.el);
}
```

...to:

```
BlogApp.Views.Categories = Parse.View.extend({

    className: 'sidebar-module',

    template: Handlebars.compile($('#menu-logged-out-tpl').html()),

    render: function() {
        var collection = { category: this.collection.toJSON() };
        this.$el.html(this.template(collection));
    }

});
```

As it stands, in the second block of code above, I'm currently only rendering #menu-logged-out-tpl, but I would like to make it conditional on whether the user is logged in or not, as before.

**Why can't I do the following, and what should I do instead?**

```
BlogApp.Views.Categories = Parse.View.extend({

    className: 'sidebar-module',

    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    if (currentUser) {
        template: Handlebars.compile($('#menu-logged-in-tpl').html()),
    } else {
        template: Handlebars.compile($('#menu-logged-out-tpl').html()),
    }

    render: function() {
        var collection = { category: this.collection.toJSON() };
        this.$el.html(this.template(collection));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using an `if` inside an object, you can't do that. Use a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to assign the template value.

```
BlogApp.Views.Categories = Parse.View.extend({
    className: 'sidebar-module',
    template: Handlebars.compile(Parse.User.current() ? $('#menu-logged-in-tpl').html() : $('#menu-logged-out-tpl').html()),
    render: function() {
        var collection = {
            category: this.collection.toJSON()
        };
        this.$el.html(this.template(collection));
    }
});
```